# How to find Firefox extension disabled status

Tags: arrays, firefox, firefox-addon

Is there way to find Firefox extension disabled status?

I can able to detect extension installed status with following script.

```
var autoform_img = document.createElement("img");

autoform_img.addEventListener("load", function(e){
    console.log( 'installed successfully' );
    btn = "<button onclick='fireKey()' class='btn btn-success pull-right' id='copy'> Copy</button>";
    $('#btn-con').append( btn );

}, false);

autoform_img.addEventListener("error", function(e){
    console.log( 'extension not installed on your machine' );
    btn = "<button onclick='fireKey()' class='btn btn-success pull-right' id='copy'> Install </button>";
    $('#btn-con').append( btn );
}, false);

autoform_img.setAttribute("src", "chrome://autoform/skin/firebug64.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AddonManager jsm there's a status property on addons

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Addons%2FAdd-on_Manager

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Addons%2FAdd-on_Manager%2FAddonManager

Comment: Is it  possible get addOn status with use of Javascript or Jquery? 

Many Thnaks,

muni

Comment: You can't use jquery in addon privelaged scope. But javascript of course thats all it is in privelaged scope, did you read the articles i gave you? Theres copy paste code in there

Comment: I think that is Java code... I don't have knowledge in Java...

can u pls help  to status with the help of Javascript?

Many Thanks,
muni

Comment: That is not java at all, that is javascript from privelaged scope. Are you writing a firefox addon? Or a website?

Comment: Hi there... Is it possible to use that within my website?

Comment: Wow ok you didn't make that clear at all in your topic. No you can't do it in your website unless you create an addon and give your website permission to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is copy paste. Paste this to your scratchpad, set environment to browser. It tells you if the addon AdBlock Plus is enabled. I chose this addon because everyone has it installed i think.

```
//this checks to see if AdBlock Plus is enabled
AddonManager.getAddonsByIDs(["{d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}"], function ([aAddon1]) {
    console.log(aAddon1);
    var isAddonEnabled = aAddon1.isActive;
    alert('AdBlock plus enabled = ' + isAddonEnabled)
    //for other properties see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/Addon#Required_properties
});
```

Comment: I had added following code in my javscript file, but it throughs following errors
TypeError: Components.utils is undefined

Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
 AddonManager.getAddonsByIDs(["{d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}"], function ([aAddon1]) {
     console.log(aAddon1);
     var isAddonEnabled = aAddon1.isActive;
     alert('AdBlock plus enabled = ' + isAddonEnabled)
     //for other properties see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/Addon#Required_properties
 });

Comment: Yes it will not work in a website, this works from privelaged code.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { Cu } = require("chrome");
let AddonManager = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm").AddonManager;
AddonManager.getAddonByID( "jid1-Ek4rsiwaZyfJnw@jetpack123" , function(addons){
     if ( !addons ) {
          addonStatus.push({
            status : 'not installed'
          });
      } else {
           addonStatus.push({
            status : 'installed',
            id: addons.id,
            appDisabled: addons.appDisabled,
           });
      }

    console.log( addonStatus );
});
```

use above script to get status of your extension installed status.....

please refer this you have any doubt

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/02/16/using-jsm-modules-in-the-sdk/